# Can I have the cursor start on a particular column by default in jqgrid's edit mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

When editing a row on jqgrid, the cursor automatically enters the left-most editable field. Is there a way to have it default to a particular column, or better yet, to whatever column I click on?

Comment: there are some additional options which one can/want to use additionally. I posted previously some answers with a little different implementations of the behavior. So it's important to know which version and which fork of jqGrid you use. Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32704985/315935) for example which uses the last version of free jqGrid. The oldest answer about the subject is probably [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6538102/315935).

Comment: Ah, unfortunately we're using 4.8, not 5.0, which it looks like is when `focusField` was added :/

Comment: 5.0 is the version number of [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Free jqGrid is my alternatively fork of jqGrid. It exist in versions 4.8.0, 4.9.0, 4.9.1, 4.9.2 (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/releases)). **Which fork you use: free jqGrid or Guriddo jqGrid JS**? `focusField` option exist starting with jqGrid 4.7 (see [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.inlinedit.js#L46)). The approach from the oldest answer can be implemented without `focusField` at all.

Comment: Do you read my answer?

Comment: Yes, but I had another project that came up that has priority over this one, sorry. Not sure when I'll be back to it.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation depend on the version of jqGrid and from the fork of jqGrid which you use.

If you use the latest version of free jqGrid then the code

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
    var $self = $(this), savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");

    if (savedRow.length > 0 && savedRow[0].id !== rowid) {
        $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
    }

    $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid, { focusField: e.target });
},
inlineEditing: { keys: true, defaultFocusField: "amount", focusField: "amount" }
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/focusOfEditRow.htm). The above code uses `e.target` as the value of `focusField` property of jqGrid method `editRow`. As the result the focus will be set on the clicked cell. If the user clicks on non-editable cell, like on "rownumber" column for example, then the option `defaultFocusField` will be used and the focus will be set on the column `"amount"`. I remind that free jqGrid uses `inlineEditing` option to specify default parameters of inline editing (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) for more details).

The option `focusField` of `editRow` is supported starting with version 4.7, but old version support only boolean and number values.